# Why is git2r unable to open repository at 'path'?

Tags: r, git

After updating the `git2r` package, `devtools::install` fails on one of my packages (all others work fine). `install` calls `git2r::repository`, which returns the following error:

```
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class "git_repository" object: Unable to open repository at 'path'
```

What can be done to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out (by comparison with the working packages) that the `/.git/config` file contained an empty line at the end. Deleting it solved the problem.

Comment: Even though a trivial fix, this sounds like a bug to me, and therefore should be [reported to the developers](https://github.com/ropensci/git2r/issues). (That is, `git` deals with blank lines just fine, so I believe it is not a requirement of the underlying infrastructure to restrict, so should not be done in `git2r`.)